# animate div backward as the same path it moved forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four positions to make circle div moving towards the mouseClick, and I want to make it moving back through the same path when clicking on previous circle ..

Here the HTML

```
<div id="box">
        <div class="circle active" id="c"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="c1"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="c2"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="c3"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="c4"></div>
</div>
```

and this the tow functions to moving the circle forward and backward

```
var current = $('#c'), past;
function forward(){
            $('.circle').click(function (event){                 
                $(this).addClass('active');
                var x = event.pageX,
                    y = event.pageY;
                past = current;
                current = $(this);

                $('#c').animate({
                    top: y - 207,
                    left: x - 207
                }, 500);                   
            });              
        };
        function backword(){
            $('.circle').click(function (){                  
                   $('#c').animate({
                        //How to use prevUntil the circle that clicked  here 
                   }, 1000);
            });
        };
```

I tried to use PrevUntil() many times but I have syntactic problem .. 
How to make circle go back on same circles it has passed?

DEMO
https://jsfiddle.net/mr2u9v7L/

Comment: create a fiddle demo or add its `css`

Comment: a jsfiddle would be of great help here

Comment: I updated It with JFiddle

Comment: A. I think you should manage the 'history' animations by yourself. Just push the index in each click and back button will get the info from it. B. If I understand what that you want to do, use `offset` (http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead `event.pageX` or `event.pageY`